# Safely copying `const char *` into struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I'm trying to create an instance of a struct with a const member.

Because the member is const, I'm creating a temporary value that has it initialized explicitly.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Thing {

    const char *value;

} Thing;

void createThing(const char *value) {
    
    // Create a temporary instance of Thing to initialize the const value
    Thing temporary = {
        .value = value
    };
    
    // Create a new thing
    Thing *thing = (Thing *)malloc(sizeof(Thing));
    if(thing == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Copy the contents of temporary into the result
    memcpy(thing, &temporary, sizeof(Thing));

    // Return the result
    return thing;
}
```

Is it safe to use `value` this way, or should I create a new copy? For example:

```
const char *valueCopy = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(value) + 1));
strcpy(valueCopy, value);
```

My reasoning is that the argument `value` will fall out of scope after the function call ends, and without copying, the value in the struct will become invalid.

---

As a side-note, I think I'm doing the right thing by copying from a temporary struct, but glad to be told otherwise.

Comment: `memcpy` will perform a shallow copy of the struct. That is, it will copy the value of the `value` pointer, not what it is pointing to. With all the consequences. Your second snippet is one of the possible ways to go (well, you will need to assign `valueCopy` to the struct field though).

Comment: Just alloc struct and use `thing->value  = strdup(value);`

Comment: `const char *value` is not a `const` member.  It is a *non*-`const` member pointing to `const` data.

Comment: @Selvin But it's a const member, so surely can't be overwritten?

Comment: A `const` member pointing to non-`const` data would be `char * const value`.

Comment: Consider avoiding `const` structure members.  They are a lot of trouble -- more, IMO, than they are worth.  Use `const` instances of the whole structure where appropriate, or pointers to the `const`-qualified version of the structure type.

Comment: Although the question exhibits a misunderstanding of `const` declarations, that is not what it is about, and it should not have been closed as a dupe of a question about that topic.  Reopening.

Comment: No need to use a temporary struct or memcpy.  Just do `*thing = (Thing) { .value = value }` after the call to malloc.  Also declare your function to return a `Thing *`, not `void`.

Comment: And don't forget to check the return of `strdup()` for NULL-

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the side issue of `const`ness, the question exhibits an essential misunderstanding.  Here:

> Is it safe to use value this way, or should I create a new copy? For
> example:
>
> ```
> const char *valueCopy = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(value) + 1));
> strcpy(valueCopy, value);
> ```
>
> My reasoning is that the argument value will fall out of scope after
> the function call ends, and without copying, the value in the struct
> will become invalid.

Although it is true that function parameter `value` goes out of scope when execution leaves the function, that's irrelevant.  The first proposed alternative initializes a structure member from the *value* of `value`.  The structure member is a separate object from the function parameter.  The assignment makes that object refer to the same data that `value` does.  It *does not* make the member an alias for `value` itself.  The structure member has its own lifetime, separate from and (in this case) unrelated to the lifetime of the `value` parameter.  In that sense, then, **yes, it is safe to use `value` as you do in the first code snippet**.

HOWEVER, there are other reasons why you might want to make a copy of the pointed-to data, as well as reasons why you might want to avoid doing that.  It's unclear from the question which is appropriate in your particular case.  But all this is independent of the `const`ness of the member.